# How to add multi shared libraries in android ndk?

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-ndk

Currently there are many shared libraries *.so in my program, but it seems the NDK only support the main shared library that will be used by jni.

Example: Java app will use library A.so, while A.so has dependence in B, C
When i build B and C to static libraries, then use them in A.so by LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES, the app works well.
When i build  B and C to shared libraries, then use them in A.so by LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES, and load each of them by System.loadLibrary("..."), the app will crash in launching.

I want to use all other libraries as shared library so that i could keep my application flexible, how could i use multi shared libraries in android correctly?

***Append my Android.mk code:***

```
DEPENDENCE_LIBS := gthread-2.0 gmodule-2.0 gobject-2.0 glib-2.0

ifeq ($(BUILD_STATIC),true)
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := $(DEPENDENCE_LIBS)
else
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := $(DEPENDENCE_LIBS)
endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

if i define **BUILD_STATIC** as **true**, all works well, but if i define **BUILD_STATIC** as **false**, could not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually my original way is correct, i just had a spelling error in name of library.
Now when i define BUILD_STATIC as false, and load each shared library by using System.loadLibrary("lib-name"), the whole process works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think System.loadLibrary links B.so or C.so to A.so.  It's meant for loading the main library that you will call via JNI.

Does it work if A.so links to B.so and C.so when you build it?  I'm thinking that the system should know to link them in automatically.  If not, try using the [uselib](http://linux.die.net/man/2/uselib) system call.

Comment: Even i build A.so by linking with B.so and C.so(using LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := $(DEPENDENCE_LIBS)), it could not work neither. BTW, i could not let uselib(...) work as the reference

Comment: Does uselib not exist in Android or did it just not work?  If it doesn't exist, then A.so won't link when try to build it.  If it exists as an Android Linux system call, maybe you're just not calling it correctly.

Comment: uselib dose not exsit in Android, the building could not pass

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  I'd never actually used uselib() myself but it turned up in a Google search.  It must be specific to some other distro.  Instead use dlopen to load B.so and C.so, and dlclose to unload them if you need to - but you probably don't need to.

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't just work to link B.so and C.so to A.so when you build A.so.  If you don't, A.so's link should fail with unresolved symbols.  Perhaps you need to put your two extra libraries somewhere special, or do something special to tell Android that they are there?

Comment: While I would expect dlopen to work, from the posts I've read it can be problematic.  Try Googling for "dlopen Android" or "load shared library on Android" and read some of the threads.  It is likely that you will encounter some problem that has already been answered somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, after checking, System.loadLibrary("...") should be used. I had  a spelling error in a library name. Now everything works well